# How to replace the center panel of a DockLayoutPanel in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

From an EntryPoint class I load a custom build westPanel. From this WestPanel I would like to replace the center of the DockLayoutPanel present on my EntryPoint class.

Here is my EntryPoint class:

```
public class MainEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
    private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    private NorthMenu northMenu = new NorthMenu();
    private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    //other panels

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(northMenu, 40);
        dockLayoutPanel.add(mainPanel);
        //add other panels
        RootLayoutPanel panel = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        panel.add(dockLayoutPanel);     
    }
}
```

WestPanel should replace DockLayout's mainPanel with a MyOtherPanel:

```
public class WestMenu extends Composite {
    private StackLayoutPanel stackLayoutPanel = new StackLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);  
    public WestMenu(){  
        Tree configuration = new Tree();
        configuration.addSelectionHandler( new SelectionHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent event) {
                MyOtherPanel builderPanel = new MyOtherPanel();
                RootLayoutPanel panel = RootLayoutPanel.get();
                DockLayoutPanel dlp = (DockLayoutPanel)panel.getWidget(0);
                dlp.add(builderPanel);
            }           
        });
        //other init configurations
        initWidget(stackLayoutPanel);
    }   
}
```

I keep on getting an Exception saying that I can not replace it. What is the best way to replace/change the center panel of a DockLayoutPanel?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to explicitly remove the center (see javadoc of the protected `insert` method in `DockLayoutPanel`):

```
dlp.remove(currentCenterPanel);
```

But that's not very developer friendly, as you need to keep track of the center widget and always make sure you call remove before adding. I don't know why they did it like this.

Another solution could be to simple put a `SimpleLayoutPanel` as center widget and set your own center widget on this panel, via `setWidget`. That way you don't have to do the remove.

The latter technique also makes it possible to combine the implementation with the `ActivityManager` by setting the `SimpleLayoutPanel` as the display in `ActivityManager.setDiplay(...)`. As your implementation looks like the main content of your application, the `ActiviyManager` might be useful here.

Comment: thanks dude... that helped a lot :) my design isnt the best since i was not waiting for that but i can deal with that later.